# How can I make this python code run faster?

Tags: python, math, statistics, probability, weibull

I have two questions:

1- This code takes too long to execute. Any idea how I can make it faster?
With the code bellow I want generate 100 random discrete values between 700 and 1200.

I choosed the weibull distribution because I wanted to generate failure rates data please see the histogram bellow.

```
    import random
    nums = [] 
    alpha = 0.6
    beta = 0.4
        
    while len(nums) !=100: 
        temp = int(random.weibullvariate(alpha, beta))
        if 700 <= temp <1200:
            nums.append(temp)
            print(nums)
            
    # plotting a graph 
    #plt.hist(nums, bins = 200) 
    #plt.show()
    print(nums)
```

I wanted to generate a histogram like this one:
[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq83c.png)

2- I have this function for discrete weibull distribution

```
def DiscreteWeibull(q, b, x):
    return q**(x**b) - q**((x + 1)**b)
```

How can I generate random values that follow this distribution?

Comment: What is a "discrete" number?

Comment: How do you expect to get values between 700 and 1200? Does the weibull function ever approach such high values? Seems like the probability of generating a value over 700 is near zero.

Comment: Right. When I add a print statement right after the line where `temp` is assigned, I see mostly numbers below 10 - so I guess it takes really long to get numbers over 700.

Comment: @SamMatzko Thre is discrete and continuous distribution. With the code above I want to generate random discrete values

Comment: @not_speshal I dont understand what you mean. I just want to generate random number between 700 and 1200 that follow a discrete weibull distribution

Comment: @mahmoudihocine So, do the built-in python random modules (`random`, `secrets`) not work for you?

Comment: @mahmoudihocine - "the probability of generating a value over 700 is near zero." That's why your code takes forever to run. You *almost* never get values between 700 and 1200 for a Weibull distribution with your parameters.

Comment: @not_speshal. I wanted to generate a failure rates data  and I could only come up with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Weibull distribution with shape parameter K and scale parameter lambda can be characterized as this function on the Uniform (0,1) dist. U, [image: Formula] we can 'cut' the distribution to a desired minimum and maximum value. We do this by inverting the equation, setting W to 700 or 1200, and finding the values between 0 and 1 that correspond. Here's some sample code.

```py
def weibull_from_uniform(shape, scale, x):
    assert 0 <= x <= 1
    return scale * pow(-1 * math.log(x), 1.0 / shape)


scale_param = 0.6
shape_param = 0.4

min_value = 700.0
max_value = 1200.0

lower_bound = math.exp(-1 * pow(min_value / scale_param, shape_param))
upper_bound = math.exp(-1 * pow(max_value / scale_param, shape_param))

if lower_bound > upper_bound:
    lower_bound, upper_bound = upper_bound, lower_bound


nums = []

while len(nums) < 100:
    nums.append(weibull_from_uniform(shape_param, scale_param, random.uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound)))

print(nums)
plt.hist(nums, bins=8)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]

This code gives a histogram very similar to the one you provided; the method will give values from the same distribution as your original method, just faster. Note that this direct approach only works when our shape parameter K <= 1, so that the density function is strictly decreasing. When K > 1, the Weibull density function increases to a mode, then decreases, so you may need to draw from two uniform intervals for particular min and max values (since inverting for W and U may give two answers).

Comment: @user:16757174 thanks. From where did you get the W equation? I want to understand it

Comment: @mahmoudihocine The equation can be found in many places; I saw this one on the wikipedia article for "Weibull Distribution", but the same equation comes up in the numpy documentation for numpy.random.weibull, or the source code for python's random.weibullvariate which uses the formula to generate values.

Comment: Is it possible to use this idea for discrete distribution?

Comment: @mahmoudihocine I'm not aware of a way, but I haven't worked with the Discrete Weibull distribution before. To use this idea, you would need to find a more common random distribution that can be transformed into the Discrete Weibull. Since there's already a built in Weibull generator into NumPy, I'd recommend checking out an actual scientific computing package

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on why you thought using this Weibull distribution was a good idea, nor what distribution you are looking to achieve.

### Discrete uniform distribution

Here are two ways to achieve the discrete uniform distribution on `[700, 1200)`.

**1) With [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)**

```py
import random

nums = [random.randrange(700, 1200) for _ in range(100)]
```

**2) With [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)**

```py
import numpy

nums = numpy.random.randint(700, 1200, 100)
```

### Geometric distribution

You have edited your question with an example histogram, and the mention "I wanted to generate a histogram like this one". The histogram vaguely looks like a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

We can use [`numpy.random.geometric`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html):

```py
import numpy

n_samples = 100
p = 0.5
a, b = 50, 650
cap = 1200

nums = numpy.random.geometric(p, size = 2 * n_samples) * a + b
nums = nums[numpy.where(nums < cap)][:n_samples]
```

Comment: I wanted the weibull distribution to generate a failure rates data. Like in this histogram
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq83c.png

Comment: @mahmoudihocine Well, then I'm guessing you need to adjust parameters alpha and beta of your formula for the weibull distribution, so that it fits in [700, 1200)

Comment: @user:3080723 thanks for helping. Do you have any resources on how to find out the right parameters? what should I google?

Comment: @mahmoudihocine I don't know. Why did you want to use ther weibull distribution in the first place? Did you read about it somewhere? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @user:3080723. I read about it. Here https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue14/relbasics14.htm

Comment: @mahmoudihocine, `alpha` is the scale parameter. Increasing the value of `alpha` will stretch the distribution to the right. You can increase the likelihood of a random value within [700, 1200) by increasing `alpha`. Please note that this does have a significant effect on reliability characteristics of whatever you're modeling. You need to find the parameters used to create the example distribution if you expect your distribution to match it.